# Using real time kernel headers to compile userspace code vs default headers

Tags: linux, centos

Per customer requirements, I installed CentOS 5.6 with the default kernel.  With this kernel installed, the time.h file includes the #define CLOCK_MONOTONIC.

Now, a real-time kernel was installed along with the kernel-devel and our code would like to use CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW.  It does exist as a part of the kernel's header files, but when I compile our code, it does not find it in the standard userspace includes.

My question is, what is the proper procedure to including/replacing the time.h found by default with the real-time kernel?  From my research, it looks like symlinks are bad, so how should it be handled?  What is the procedure or process?  Upgrading to CentOS 6.0 or 5.7 is not an option per customer requirements.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, userspace code uses userspace headers. Kernel modules use kernel headers (and that's why symlinks are bad, because you would be mixing userspace code with kernel headers).

To get the definition of CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, you will have to update glibc — for CLOCK_ definitions, the "borderline" (they still count as userspace though!) headers in /usr/include/linux are not used.

With CentOS 5 default install, you are screwed, because both glibc (2.5) and the kernel (2.6.18) are too old; glibc-2.12 (commit glibc-2.12~111) and kernel-2.6.28 are the first to have MONOTONIC_RAW. That means it's got to be CentOS 6, or something else better.

You can try cheating your way in by using something like `#ifndef CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, #define CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW 4, #endif` in your code, but that counts as unportable.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response.  That is the clearest answer I could find anywhere, so thank you for the explanation.  I am using an updated kernel than 2.6.18, yet the header files are still located in the "src" directory.  Is there a procedure to copying the real-time kernel header files into the glibc location?  Am I making any sense?  Thank you again for your response.

Comment: You can't just walk into M.... you can't just overwrite glibc's bits/time.h by linux's time.h, that just is never going to work.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW is in /usr/local/include/linux/time.h on our Fedora 11 install but this header appears to be basically unusable .  It doesn't declare clock_gettime or define clockid_t but it happily defines struct timerspec and struct itimerspec.  The former is preceded by "#ifndef _STRUCT_TIMESPEC" so you can turn it off, but the latter is completely unprotected, which means that you can't include  and  in the same file without getting conflicting definitions.

There might be some contortion of #include directives that you could use to get this working using the headers in /usr/include, but I gave up and just copied the linux version to the source code directory for my project and then commented out the extra junk that I didn't need.  So much for portability.